Код css для иконок соцсетей
Я настраиваю тему для wordpress. Непонятная ситуация с блоком соцсетей, нужно сменить иконки. Например, иконка ОК (Одноклассники). Нужно добавить css код для иконки ОК? Где его взять?
Демо: https://demos.afthemes.com/broadnews/blog/


Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

"Где его взять?" -- написать

А у тебя в заначке случайно нет такого кода? Я не программист

Тут вопрос не "где взять" (ибо это легко гуглиться), а как "внедрить в тему". С этим вопросом обращайся к производителю/документации темы. Или забей на этот родной функционал темы и напиши свой html-код со всему нужными значками. (опять же это можно нагуглить)

Вообще не понятно, что вы хотите. Если ОК уже есть в списке виджета, значит и иконка уже есть, если его нет в списке и вы хотите добавить её, то у вас не получится, так как она добавляется при помощи этого виджета готового сгенерированного css. Например Facebook вызывается так -  content: "\f09a", но прикол в том, что она подтягивается с этого виджета и если где-то в другом месте написать -     content: "\f09a", он просто не поймёт что это за f09a.

По ссылке ниже сможете найти код для отображения ваших иконок в формате CSS или HTML:
https://developer.wordpress.org/resource/dashicons/#editor-underline

Ссылки на внешние ресурсы — это прекрасно, но оставьте вместе со ссылкой описание, чтобы другие пользователи имели представление о её содержимом. Всегда цитируйте самую необходимую информацию, которую вы взяли из указанного источника, на случай если он станет недоступным или навсегда закрытым.
